# What is the difference between "required" vs "optional" in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Sometimes, I noticed the following JSON Schemas:

```
{
    "type": "object",   
    "properties": {
        "address": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "required": true
            }
     }

}
```

vs

```
{
    "type": "object",   
    "properties": {
        "address": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "optional": false
            }
     }

}
```

So what is the difference between `required` vs `optional` in the above example?

Comment: Note: this is a very old question, and `optional` no longer exists in the latest versions of JSON Schema. All properties are optional by default, and `required` is used to make them required.

Comment: Does this also mean that any key that has not been specified as allowed will be acceptable? How do you prohibit keys that have not been defined in the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the object must have a non-`undefined` value for the `address` property (if `required`).

Answer (score 43):

The [IETF draft v4](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) of the JSON schema
only defines `required` and does not include `optional`.

To quote the [section](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor61) on `required` from draft v4:

> **Valid values:** The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array MUST have
>   at least one element. Elements of this array MUST be strings, and MUST be 
>   unique.
>
> **Conditions for successful validation:** An object instance is valid against this
>   keyword if its property set contains all elements in this keyword's array 
>   value.

In effect, using `required` makes optional all properties for which
the name is not included in the given array of strings.

Comment: I can't say why but required seems to be empty in the link. The link is correct though

Comment: @erikb85 In the [link](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor61), "5.4.3. required" is only an overall header; the two sub-sections underneath it detail the "required" keyword usage.

Comment: Ah okay, that was really not clear just from looking at the doucment. Your formatting is way more clear in my eyes.

Comment: This link has an example and is a bit easier to follow: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties

Answer (score 26):

Actually, they are equivalent expressions, but using different versions of the standard.

`optional` is from v2, `required` is from v3.  You should make sure you are using the correct one for your tool (although ideally you should move to v4 if you can).