# Optional parameter in json schema validation

Tags: json, jsonschema

I saw some json schema where optional keyword is used. Also heard that optional keywords no longer exist. Is this true?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204871/what-is-the-difference-between-required-vs-optional-in-json-schema
Here in comment section of question.

Comment: Should be closed a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204871/what-is-the-difference-between-required-vs-optional-in-json-schema